# Back up Application before undeployment - JBoss EAP 6 Managed Domain

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss6.x

In Standalone mode, I just need to copy from the deployments directory, but it is possible to back up an application before undeployment in Managed Domain, assuming I have the admin right for the domain controller.

I would like to have a programmatical method to do so (like with jboss-cli)
Thanks for any reply

Answer (score 2):

The steps to keep backup of an undeployed application using CLI are :

1. Deploy the application.

   deploy /home/Desktop/Example.war

   You can check the content of application in data directory
2. undeploy the application but keep its content in data directory.

   ```
   undeploy Example.war --keep-content
   ```

   You can check that content of application still in data directory.
3. Now deploy other application

   deploy /home/Desktop/Test.war

   Now you can see that both the applications are present in your data directory.

Comment: I found the solution. It is quite similar to what u wrote: In the data directory, the application is stored in:ls domain/content/47/95cc29338b5049e238941231b36b3946952991. Where the long characters are hash of the app, and available using CLI. Thanks anyway